# Mac 10.7.3 Web Sharing Won't Start

Tags: macos, sharing, apache

When I turn it on it says "starting" for a split second and then turns back off. I reinstalled Lion and it still happens. Trying to start it from the command line:

```
cade:~> sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons /org.apache.httpd.plist
org.apache.httpd: Already loaded
```

Okay... But...

```
cade:~> ps aux | grep apache
cade            1137   0.0  0.0  2434892    540 s000  S+    2:32AM   0:00.00 grep apache
```

I replaced httpd.conf with the default one, and that didn't help either. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: The process for web sharing is called httpd, not apache.

Comment: Wouldn't it still show up because apache is in the name of the launch daemon? Anyway, I still get the same results.

Comment: Have you tried… sudo apachectl start

Comment: `cade:~> sudo apachectl start`
`org.apache.httpd: Already loaded`